# using value of *ngfor in template variable

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngfor

i have to use a select tag for selecting type of social handles
[image]

i have stored an array of the possible values of select in an array in .ts file.

```
socialHandleOptions=['Website', 'Facebook', 'Instagram', 'LinkedIn'];
```

i am using *ngfor to iterate over the values, but i am not getting it in another tag, as i need to store the values corresponding to a particular social handle formcontrol field.

i tried using template variables, but couldn't get the values.

```
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5">
                  <select>
                    <option *ngFor="let handle of socialHandleOptions" #hnd >{{handle}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7 pl-sm-1">
                  <input type="text" formControlName={{hnd}} placeholder="Enter URL">
                </div>
                <a (click)="handleConsole(hnd)"><img src="assets/img/profile/minus.svg" alt=""></a>
              </div>
```

Comment: I can't figure out what the problem is. what error message are you getting?

Comment: the reference variable i put i.e. #hnd in select > option tag is not available to use for formControlName or other lines..

suppose i select "website" from the dropdownlist, the value which i put in the text input should be corresponding to the "website" , and so further for instagram, facebook and linkedin

Comment: can you share more of your code , it 's not clear how do you use formGroup or formArray , how do you setup the form ? 

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your selected option to one variable and then use that variable in another tag. It may resolve your issue.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<input type="text" formControlName="selectedValue" placeholder="Enter URL">
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand form the picture you have formArray and you have a dropdown list of social and link related to the selected social account type this mean you may have  two record related to **Facebook** as example

template

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let fg of socialForm.controls">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5" [formGroup]="fg">
        <select formControlName="socialAccountType">
      <option *ngFor="let handle of socialHandleOptions"  >{{handle}}</option>
    </select>

        <input type="text" formControlName="link" placeholder="Enter URL">
  </div>

</ng-container>

<button (click)="addNew()">Add New ➕</button>

<pre>{{socialForm.value | json}}</pre>
```

component

```js
  socialForm :FormArray;
  socialHandleOptions=['Website', 'Facebook', 'Instagram', 'LinkedIn'];

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){
    this.socialForm = fb.array([this.getFormGroupItem()])
  }

  getFormGroupItem() : FormGroup{
    return this.fb.group({
      socialAccountType:null,
      link:null
    })
  }

  addNew(){
     this.socialForm.push(this.getFormGroupItem())
  }
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ikyh)

another case using formGroup the have a form controls of social types ,but I 'm still not sure about the plus icon next the link input

template

```html
<div [formGroup]="socialForm">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let c of socialHandleOptions">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5">
            <label>{{c}}</label>
            <input type="text" [formControlName]="c | lowercase" placeholder="Enter URL">
  </div>

    </ng-container>
</div>
```

component

```js
 socialForm: FormGroup;
  socialHandleOptions = ["Website", "Facebook", "Instagram", "LinkedIn"];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.socialForm = this.fb.group({
      website: null,
      facebook: null,
      instagram: null,
      linkedin: null
    });
  }
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ikyh-pcq4uq)

Comment: the plus icon is for the functionality,  the user can dynamically create a new field to enter one of the remaining options, a user can select the social handles only once. if a user from the dropdown selects a option like facebook, after that he clicks on the + sign, a new row shall appear, dropdown and input, but in the dropdown, facebook option shall not be available.

Comment: can you please help me to implement the above functionality.. also the minus sign is to remove a particular row.